# how to install opencv for python3.7 when default python3 is python3.5

Tags: python3, opencv

I am trying to install opencv for my JetsonTX1. I have to build OpenCV from source CMake follow the link 
https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2018/06/04/build-opencv-3-4-with-cuda-on-nvidia-jetson-tx1/
The issue is Jetson has python 3.5 as default Python. I would like to update to python3.7. I used update-alternatives to switch python3 point to python3.7. But when I build the opencv with CMake, it still choose python3 interpreter as Python 3.5. Is there a way to force install opencv for python3.7?

Comment: Have you considered virtual environments, isn't that the pythonic way to manage versions? You could also try `pip3.7` instead.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere: I really don't know how to build OpenCV for Python 3.7 using virtual environments. I thought it's for install only.

Comment: @ThangNguyen, how did you install Python3.7? Did you build from source using `make install`? What is the output of command `python3.7 -V`?

Answer (score 0):

for python3.x ,try  pip3 command

```
sudo pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade opencv-python
```